# Blazor Server + Azure App Service deployment slots: active production users keep on using old SignalR connection slot after swap

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, azure-deployment-slots

when setting up deployment slots for our Blazor Server web app using Asp.Net Identity authentication, we stumbled upon the problem of every user getting logged out after swapping slots. Following [Swapping Azure Web App deployment slots logs out all users in ASP.NET Core RC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849816/swapping-azure-web-app-deployment-slots-logs-out-all-users-in-asp-net-core-rc2) and other sources, we got it working to keep users logged in.

However, active production users now keep on using the old version after a swap until they next initiate a new SignalR session (e.g. by hitting the browser's refresh button). Is there a way to force active users into a refresh after a swap in order to get them to use the new version of the application? At the same time we want to avoid stepping back to the initial problem of all users getting logged out.

KR,
Gerhard